# Pine Script beginner question work with arrays --> create a new out of exisiting overwrite some values

Tags: pine-script, indicator

don't know, why i cannot find an answer in the internet for my easy problem.
Just new in PineScript and the only I want to do is to create build an own array based with some specified values plus the input as source and get an sma out of it:

```
src = input(close, title="Source")
length = 10
lastBar = 1234 //overwrite the last bar of the input source

newSource[0]=lastBar

for i = 1 to length-2
     newSource[i] = src[i]

newSMA= sma(foreCastSourceFull, length)
plot(newSMA, color=orange)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are no arrays in Pine, there are [series](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#series) and they are immutable. You can use [barstate.islast](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Dislast) to override the last bar:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
newSource = barstate.islast ? 1234 : close
newSMA = sma(newSource, 10)
plot(newSMA)
```

**UPDATE**

Use the following script if you want to duplicate the last bar (works on active markets only):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

plot(close)

LastClose = barstate.islast and not barstate.isconfirmed ? close : na
plot(LastClose, offset=1)
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much. And is there also a possibility to just add one or more values at the end of the series, not to overwrite?

Comment: No, but you can shift series to the "future" area with the offset parameter of plot: plot(close, offset=5)

Comment: Ah great, but that also would not keep the full series if i overwrite the last one? Indeed i want to double the current bar and copy it to the future candle...

Comment: I've updated the answer with the script that duplicates close of the last bar and draws it in the future, take a look, please.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks. But this here is not working then...?


foreCastBasisSMA = sma(LastClose, 20)

Comment: You should create a new series first (`SMA = sma(close, 20)`), and then calculate the last value from it (`LastValue = barstate.islast and not barstate.isconfirmed ? SMA : na`).

Comment: Mh, think I haven't described well: so what I want is to create an SMA on the full series PLUS - INCLUDING the duplicated last candle. And later I also want to calculate the standard deviation on the full series plus/indcluding the last candle duplicated e.g.: 

sma(Close including LastClose,20)
stdev(Close including LastClose,20)

Comment: I believe, the only way you can do that is by writing your own versions of `sma` and `stdev` which will duplicate the last bar during calculation. [Here](https://gist.github.com/fppden/6d5fff014026cbef587932fa1940498d) is an example for SMA.

Comment: Really getting crazy with this  :D

But shouldn't it be this way to work?


CustomSMA(source, length) =>
    sum = source[0]                (<-- Add the latest a second time)
    for i = 0 to length-2            (<-- All Candles -minus last, swapped with first double)
        sum := sum + source[i]       
    sum / length                       (<-- Average of all including second last)

Comment: I can't understand your question, sorry :-) Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: :-)

So more concrete, think in you example
 **sum = source**  should be **sum = source[0]** ???

Comment: Those notations are the same thing. In fact, you can think about `series[1]` like a `series` moved to the right for one bar (the most recent bar is lost in this case). So `source[0]` and `source` are just synonyms. :-)